# Is it possible to disassemble C code into intel assembly using an m1 mac?

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, apple-m1, intel-syntax

I've been trying to disassemble C code into intel assembly code on my m1 macbook pro but can't find any way to do it (i've tried to look up how to do it using gdb, lldb, objdump, but no succes so far). So my question is: is it possible and if so, how and with which library/program? Would it also be possible to do with an IDE like CLion or Xcode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “disassemble” here.  C code is *compiled* into assembly or machine code.  If you compile to machine code, you can then *disassemble* the machine code into assembly code, but going directly from C to assembly is usually a better idea.  Anyway, have you tried passing something like `-target amd64` to the C compiler?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to use https://godbolt.org/ online compiler + disassembler. I use that one even though I have x86 disassemblers available locally.

Comment: The LLVM option that some tools use is `--x86-asm-syntax=intel`, e.g. for `llvm-objdump -d`.  But disassembly is useful if you have *machine code*.  If you're compiling in the first place from C, that option can make clang emit Intel-syntax asm.

Comment: Actual GDB has an option `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Comment: I don't have access to an M1 Mac, but do you have `otool`?   On intel macs, otool disassembles x86, arm; so I would hope the same would be true on an M1.

Comment: if you can run clang or gcc on an m1 mac, then of course you can make a cross toolchain and use that toolchain for whatever target is supported by gcc or clang

Comment: I suspect the actual answer you're after is due to a misunderstanding. Unless you're cross-compiling, the native code generated for an M1 uses the 64-bit ARM instruction set (ARMv8.x / AArch64).

Comment: Disassembly is the process of representing machine code as assembly mnemonics.  The fact that machine code may have been generated from C source code is irrelevant, it is machine code, not C code.

You can of course _compile_ C code to assembly.  The compiler is capable of outputting an assembly listing of the generated machine code.

However, if it is ARM machine code then clearly, it cannot be represented in Intel x86 assembly as it is an entirely different instruction set. So your question is ambiguous to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did it on a M1 Mac.

First build your .c file with

```
clang -arch x86_64 -O0 -g file.c -o out
```

To get your x86 assembly output you can use one of the following commands

`objdump -Sd out > asm.s`

`objdump -drwC -Mintel out > asm.s`

Comment: `-arch` isn't a GCC option, I don't think.  I assume that only works if the `gcc` command is actually Clang, like on a Mac where you haven't installed real GCC with `brew`.  I'd recommend writing it as `clang -arch x86_64` ... if that's the only compiler it actually works with.  (Also, you can use `-S` to get asm directly; [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) .  Although to be fair, the OP did ask for disassembly.)

Comment: Okay, fixed! I installed gcc with brew because there is more support online for gcc commands than for clang ones but it must work both ways.

Comment: I just noticed another thing.  `-masm=intel` doesn't make a difference unless you use `-S` to output asm.  (Unless your source has inline `asm("" :::)` statements, and you're using GCC or a recent clang version, then it affects which dialect is used for the inline asm).  The compile step is just making machine code, it's the `objdump` disassembly step that's making asm text in either Intel syntax or AT&T (`%` on register names, destination last, etc).  e.g. `objdump -drwC -Mintel` is good with GNU Binutils or with `llvm-objdump`.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I think I found it somewhere and added it to the command to be sure but it makes no difference for the particular purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, you can use `brew install x86_64-elf-binutils`, then you will have a set of tools which are same with what you normally used in x86 platform linux such as `x86_64-elf-gcc`, and `x86_64-elf-objdump` is one of them. Then you can easily use it as what you use `objdump` in x86 linux enviroment.

Comment: Doesn't MacOS (or at least LLVM) already come with the ability to disassemble machine code for various ISAs?  Like `llvm-objdump` or `otool` should just work on any binary.  (e.g. on my x86-64 Linux desktop, `llvm-objdump -d` can disassemble ARM / MIPS / AArch64 / etc. object files.)  For Intel-syntax disassembly of x86 code instead of AT&T, `--x86-asm-syntax=intel`.  But sure, GNU Binutils could work, too.